# Ruby: parse long string

Tags: ruby

String has repeated values - I want to extract the values in the same sequence

```
str = %q(
a
a
b
a
)
a = str.split
new_value = a[0]
flip_flop = ""
s1, s2 = "", ""
a.each{|e|
    if e == flip_flop
    s1 << e
    flip_flop = e
else
    s2 << e
    flip_flop = e
end
}
p s1 # should be aaa
p s2 # should be b
```

Expected values: s1 should be 'aaa', and s2 should be 'b'.
More realistic examples: 
String =  "xblah\nxmoreblah\nyfoo\nzbar\nxmoredata\nxblah". 
Expected: "xblahmoreblah\nyfoo\nzbar\nxmoredatablah".

String =   "ablah\namoreblah\nbfoo\nablahend"
Expected = "ablahmoreblah\nfoo\nablahend"

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear what you're asking. What is a "flip flop summary" and can you specify what you mean by "values in the same sequence"? How do you define a "sequence"? What sorts of inputs are possible; only strings with `a` and `b`?

Comment: example strings: abbbbaccca - expected result aaa,  bbbb, ccc.
xxyzxx - expected result = xxxx, y, z

Comment: OK, you're still leaving me to surmise as to what your intentions are, but the second example helps. Should your output be a list of strings, a list of lists, a hash of lists...?

Comment: I have a long file: each line (short lines with data) starts with a meaningful prefix. I want to join all the lines with the same prefix into one (long line) .
The last example would be in fact similar to this:

Comment: That muddies the waters further. I'm not sure how this question will help you with that, and you still haven't explicitly stated your transformation, only given i/o examples.

Comment: I have a long file: each line (short lines with data - ending with "\n") starts with a meaningful prefix. I want to join all the lines with the same prefix into one (long line) .
More realistic example: xblah\nxmoreblah\nyfoo\nzbar\nxmoredata\nxblah. Expected: xblahmoreblah\nyfoo\nzbar\nxmoredatablah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182179/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-adam).

Comment: When asked for clarification it's best to edit your question rather than elaborating in a series of comments. For one, not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your original example `(a,a,b,a)` => `(a,a,a),(b)` doesn't care about sequence, in which case you can use

```
str.split.group_by(&:itself).values.map(&:join)
 => ["aaa", "b"]
```

If you do care about the sequence, as your next examples would suggest and you expect it to actually return `(a,a),(b),(a)` then

```
str.split.chunk{ |n| n }.map {|a| a.last.join}
 => ["aa", "b", "a"]
```

Comment: Adam, in your first comment on the question you gave the example that when `str = "abbbbaccca"` the expected result is `aaa, bbbb, ccc`. I don't know if you mean  `"aaa, bbbb, ccc"` or  `["aaa", "bbbb", "ccc"]`, but either way, this answer, which you checkmarked, returns `["abbbbaccca"]` (both `group_by` and `chunk`). Please explain. In future, please ensure all values in questions are valid Ruby objects (strings quoted, etc.). I'm not criticising this answer, but don't understand how you can accept it when it appears to be inconsistent with your example.

Comment: It was made clear (in the chat) that newlines are important here, as the original problem was segregating sequences of lines in file by their prefix. So `str = "a\nb\nb..."`, therefore I went with `.split` instead of `.chars`. You are 100% correct about the confusion caused by the question though.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Ruby has a built-in flip-flop:

```
%w[a a b b a].each_with_object([[]]) do |e, acc|
  if (e != acc.last.last..e != acc.last.last) # HERE
    acc << [e]
  else
    acc.last << e end
end[1..-1]
#⇒ [["a", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["a"]]
```

— [more info](https://dev.to/mudasobwa/real-applications-of-flip-flop-in-ruby-35cj).